# COOKIE value getting destroyed on page redirect

Tags: php, cookies

Consider the following code to set Cookie via PHP.

```
setcookie('html5board',$html5boardChangeValue,time()+3600*24*7);
$_COOKIE['html5board'] = $html5boardChangeValue ;
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

This is followed by a redirect code as follows--

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '".FB_APP_PATH."?action=mysettings';</script>";
```

My problem is that although I do get the set value in the `print_r($_COOKIE)`,however,on page redirect on,html5board is not present.

Its an FB app and i m running it on my local server. Also other COOKIES set are available post redirect but not html5board.I have checked for any spelling errors-NONE.

Plz help.

Comment: when you are setting the cookie?

Comment: is there any action for that?

Comment: what do u mean by `any action for that`? i have a redirect to index page that further redirects to another page based on the action sent (mysettings,in this case).

Comment: So on redirection you are setting the cookie